# The id of the input box in my Moodle quiz keeps changing! You know, the kinda id with a colon inside

Tags: jquery, input, moodle

The id of the input box in my Moodle quiz keeps changing!

One moment the id was `q1525:32_sub1_answer`, the next moment (when I opened the course page in Firefox), it is `q1526:32_sub1_answer`!

```
<input id="q1526:32_sub1_answer" type="text" maxlength="14" size="14" name="q1526:32_sub1_answer"></input>
```

Here is my JQuery code that I use to highlight (I change the highlighted elemetn to a different background colour) another element (id is 'advice') whenever I detect that the user has clicked inside the input box.

```
$("q1524:36_sub1_answer").focus(function(){
    $("#advice").css("background-color","#FFFFA7"); 
});
```

As you can see, I hardcoded the id as `q1524:36_sub1_answer` inside my Jquery code. The problem is that Moodle keeps dynamically creating a new `q9999:` prefix id to the id of the input box. So my JQuery code is practically useless. Kinda like the broken watch that is accurate only twice a day.

Need a little help here. Anyone? ANYONE???

Frankie Kam

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to look at creating a theme. Inherit an existing theme, then override the style for the quiz.

http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Themes_overview

Comment: Thanks, Russell. Yeah, I really need to sink my teeth into the Moodle.org docs for a strong foundation first! Much appreciated.

Comment: Oh Okay, Russell. I got it. See mah answer above. I found it in them there Internet forrest.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do it. Referring to this post entitled 'Handling Colon in Element ID in JQuery – Visualforce problem', 
http://shivasoft.in/blog/others/tips/handling-colon-in-element-id-in-jquery-visualforce-problem/
Specifically the comment by a certain 'John', quote:

*"I generally just use a selector like $("input[id$=blahblah]") because what's before the colon, and the colon itself, are generally dynamic anyway. **Basically, that jQuery finds all inputs that have an ID that END with the string "blahblah".** Works very well and is less of a hassle then worrying about escaping the colon all the time."*

So to solve my problem, I substituted the hardcoded

```
    $("q1524:36_sub1_answer").focus(function(){
        $("#advice").css("background-color","#FFFFA7"); 
    });
```

with this Regex-like code on the first line:

```
    $("input[id$=36_sub1_answer]").focus(function(){
        $("#advice").css("background-color","#FFFFA7"); 
    });
```

So the solution is I used this code:
**input[id$=36_sub1_answer]** which simple means, match any element id that ends with the string 36_sub1_answer. Igor!! PULL the...SWITCH!!!! It vorks!!! It's alive!!! I created you!!!!! Harhahaharhahahahr....!!!

Regards
Frankie 'mad scientist' Kam